# Equipping the dagger vs the shield

Tags: weapons, equipment, armor, statistics

I want to figure out what is the better option, straight up damage or a chance to deflect in a game.

I have two options, the first is to equip another dagger for 10% more damage. However, this characters I am using gets a 4x bonus to attack as it is compared to others, so I am not sure if that factors in. (So damage*4*1.10 pretty much)

The other is to equip a shield that has a 15% chance to deflect. The amount deflected is between 20%-50% when deflect occurs.

If I fought an exact replica, let's say the same character, one with the extra dagger, and the other with the shield, is there a way to determine what is the better one to use? If I had to put numbers, let's say we have 2000 hit points, and 500 damage per attack with just the 4x bonus.. In terms of 'average' since I know deflect is really % based for both the chance to deflect and the amount.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. Kindly take the [tour]. I'm afraid we cannot answer the question without knowing the details of the system you're playing with.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to make a [tag:system-agnostic] question about general game statistics. This is likely to be too broad for the site without a particular system. If you are talking about a single system please [edit] in the appropriate system tag so we can answer with the context.

Comment: It also kind of sounds like this might be a video game question, with those enormous damage numbers. (Video games are off topic here.)

Comment: Ah okay! Sorry, I was redirected here by math.stackexchange.com after they said it's kind of a math question but not and should post here. I'll probably just delete this.